# Loop through Kendo Grid Column values - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, kendo-grid

What is correct way to loop through Kendo Grid Column Values in JavaScript and perform an if statement on the values:

```
    var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    // Gets the full set of data from the data source
    var allData = dataSource.data();
    dataSource.fetch();
    var datasourcedata = dataSource.data();

    var dataitem = datasourcedata[i].(columnName);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataitem.value; i++) {
        if (dataitem.value == 0) {
            alert("error message");
          e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

   });
```

Comment: Do you have any data showing on your grid yet and what kinda condition/if statement would you like the perform on the values of in the columns?

Comment: yes I have data. I don't want to perform data on the actual values. I just want to see what the values are and if a certain value then an external button will fire the javascript alert("error message").

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(kendoDataSource.schema.model.fields, function (propertyName, propertyValue) {
    alert(filter.field);
});
```